# Is it possible to make custom shaped CSS buttons?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button that goes on the left side of the screen that looks something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKsFX.png)

Is this possible in CSS?

So far I have tried using border-top-right-radius combined with border-bottom-right-radius expecting them to meet in the middle and make the semicircle but intead only made a square with one curved line going from one corner to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
  
  border-radius: 0 100vw 100vw 0;
}
```

```html
<button>></button>
```

There you go :D